# Cambiar dirección ip publica en Plex Media Server

Tags: vps, ubuntu-server

Ya que estoy detrás de un CGNAT me vi obligado a contratar un VPS para lograr tener una ip pública. Esto lo hago a través de DigitalOcean, cree una VPN por WireGuard para que mi Home Server que actualmente estoy corriendo Plex sea visible desde fuera de mi red privada. Cree las ip tables y todo funciona OK.
Pero el problema es que Plex obtiene automáticamente la ip pública que actualmente muestra mi CGNAT y no sé cómo cambiar esa ip por la del VPS ya que no hay opción para cambiar la ip pública.
Ambos servidores corren ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Plex media server obtiene la ip pública de forma automática y quiero modificarla, por la ip pública de mi VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que forwardeaste el puerto a tu VPS (IP Pública) configura tu nueva URL en Configuraciones > Red > URL de acceso al servidor personalizado, a mi me funcionó.